# Array of superclass objects. How to manage them as subclass ones?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

Having these classes:

```
public abstract class Furniture

public class Chair : Furniture

public class Table : Furniture

public class Kitchen
{
ArrayList <Furniture> furnitures;
//other code
public void function ()
{
  Furniture furniture = furnitures.get();
  doSomethingInKitchen(furniture);
}


private void doSomethingInKitchen (Chair c);
private void doSomethingInKitchen (Table t);

}
```

I am looking for the best practice that assures me to manipulate the Superclass Furniture object as a subclass one (Chair or Table).

I tried with a simple cast, but when I call the function it operates with the Furniture Object, not with the Table or Chair one.

What I tried is something like:

```
for each Furniture in Array List
if(furniture.get() istance of Table)
{
currentFurniture = (Table) furniture.get();
}

else if (furniture.get() istanceof Chair)
{
currentFurniture = (Chair) furniture.get();
}
doSomethingInKitchen(currentFurniture)
```

I don't know if the problem is that currentFurniture is declared as

```
Furniture currentFurniture;
```

And so it won't be recognized as Chair or Table despite of the casting or if the design itself of the solution is wrong.

Comment: polymorphism works based on the type of the object **on which** the method is called. Not on the type of the argument of the method. It should be `furniture.doSomethingInTheKitchen()`. Aso, post real Java code, not pseudo-code, when asking about errors in Java.

Comment: Just a complement on what JBNizet stated: In your example, suppose you "use" your object. In this way, you could `(Kitchen Object).furniture.get().use();`this way, you can code upper and lower classes, without worrying if the code exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your cast is lost as soon as your reassign it to the common variable. You need handle each type separately:

```
for (Furniture furniture : furnitures) {
    if (furniture instanceof Table) {
        doSomethingInKitchen((Table)furniture);
    } else if (furniture instanceof Chair) {
        doSomethingInKitchen((Chair)furniture);
    }
}
```

Ideally though, you would avoid casting altogether and implement the differing logic on the subclass itself. For example:

```
abstract class Furniture {
    abstract void doSomethingInKitchen();
}

class Table extends Furniture {
    @Override
    void doSomethingInKitchen() {
        // Table-specific logic
    }
}

class Chair extends Furniture {
    @Override
    void doSomethingInKitchen() {
        // Chair-specific logic
    }
}
```

Now in your `Kitchen` you just do

```
for (Furniture furniture : furnitures) {
    furniture.doSomethingInKitchen();
}
```

Comment: Please note that 
 
I wrote two doSomethingInKitchen function because its instructions work much more with Kitchen parameters than in (Table/Chair) ones. Edited the question according to this comment because I think it wasn't clear in the first version.

Answer (score 2):

since you are inheriting `Furniture` class theres no need of implementing `2 methods` for each `chair` and `Table`

```
private void doSomethingInKitchen (Chair c);
private void doSomethingInKitchen (Table t);
```

you can have a single method like this

```
private void doSomethingInKitchen (Furniture f);
```

and you can getRid of the casting in `forloop` and  let the method  do the casting.

```
private void doSomethingInKitchen (Furniture f){

   if(f instanceof Table){
   //code for the table 
   }else{
   //code for the chair
   } 

}
```

Comment: This is a valid answer, but if you're already refactoring, I would go with polymorphism instead.

Comment: Despite it will work, it's not considered a good practice. If you are using inheritance, why not use it's true potential overriding the methods on the children?

Comment: i just wanted to show him that , having a method for each class is not a good practise .even if op has `overriding methods` he should at somepoint `cast` the `object` since he is `iterating` the `superclass objects` otherwise he will end up executing the method in `super class`,

Comment: I wrote two doSomethingInKitchen function because its instructions work much more with Kitchen parameters than in (Table/Chair) ones. Edited the question according to this comment because I think it wasn't clear in the first version.